# YAML multi-line strings: keys vs array values

Tags: arrays, json, string, yaml, multilinestring

This is very specific but left me stumped. We treat nested keys + regular arrays almost the same on parsing – sometimes adding extra info when needed, like this:

```
---
Entry 1:
    - lorem:
        true
    - ipsum
    - dolor
Entry 2:
    - lorem
    - ipsum:
        true
    - dolor
...
```

… which gives me this JSON:

```
{
  "Entry 2": [
    "lorem", 
    {
      "ipsum": true
    }, 
    "dolor"
  ], 
  "Entry 1": [
    {
      "lorem": true
    }, 
    "ipsum", 
    "dolor"
  ]
}
```

All cool and fine. Entering multiline strings for content it gets messier but still works ok like this (keep pasting those to [Online YAML Parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) or some other compiler for reference):

```
---
#works:

Test:
  - lorem
  - ipsum
  - dolor
? |-
    multiline
    Test
:
  - lorem
  - ipsum:
      true
  - dolor
...
```

going deeper, multiline strings in my 2nd level array work as well, as expected by the spec:

```
---
#works:
Test:
    - |-
        multiline
        lorem
    - ipsum
    - dolor
? |-
    multiline
    Test
:
    - lorem
    - ipsum:
        true
    - dolor
...
```

Wohoo! But as soon as I *mix* multi-line keys and multi-line array strings on the same level, my setup breaks:

```
---
#breaks:
Test:
    - |-
        multiline
        lorem
    ? |- 
        multiline
        ipsum
    : 
        true
? |-
    multiline
    Test
:
    - lorem
    - ipsum:
        true
    - dolor
...
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YAML breaks if you mix keys and array items on the same level. You do not need multi-line strings for that:

```
- 1
? 2
: 3
```

What should this parse to? An array? A mapping? This, however, works:

```
- 1
- ? 2
  : 3
```

So you can fix your YAML like this:

```
---
Test:
    - |-
        multiline
        lorem
    - ? |- 
          multiline
          ipsum
      : 
        true
? |-
    multiline
    Test
:
    - lorem
    - ipsum:
        true
    - dolor
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for educating me on this matter!